# Eclipse Project not deploying to linux server

Tags: eclipse, jboss, wildfly

Hi I created a project in Eclipse Kepler and deployed it to my local WildFly Server and everything works fine.  I have a pretty basic project connecting to an oracle db, jpa,ejb,webproj all wrapped up in an ear. But when I try to deploy to my Linux server the following happens. 
1) It starts copying files to the standalone deployments directory  -ok
2) When it gets to about 52% it hangs at the following command"
Create Remote Directory:/usr/local/wildfly-8.1.0.Final/standalone/deployments/ADTF_EAR.ear/ADTF_EJB.jar

No Error message is displayed. but this is what is in the log file:

```
2015-01-19 20:43:12,602 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBAS017535: Unregistered web context: /ADTF_WebProj
2015-01-19 20:43:12,614 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 177) JBAS011410: Stopping Persistence Unit (phase 2 of 2) Service
'ADTF_EAR.ear#Test-Persistence'
2015-01-19 20:43:12,618 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-16) JBAS016009: Stopping weld service for deployment ADTF_EAR.ear
2015-01-19 20:43:12,625 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 177) JBAS011410: Stopping Persistence Unit (phase 1 of 2) Service
'ADTF_EAR.ear#Test-Persistence'
2015-01-19 20:43:12,633 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBAS015974: Stopped subdeployment (runtime-name: ADTF_EJB
.jar) in 34ms
2015-01-19 20:43:12,662 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-13) JBAS015974: Stopped subdeployment (runtime-name: ADTF_We
bProj.war) in 62ms
2015-01-19 20:43:12,668 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-13) JBAS015877: Stopped deployment ADTF_EAR.ear (runtime-nam
e: ADTF_EAR.ear) in 69ms
2015-01-19 20:43:12,669 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-9) JBAS015876: Starting deployment of "ADTF_EAR.ear" (runtim
e-name: "ADTF_EAR.ear")
2015-01-19 20:43:12,672 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-9) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."ADT
F_EAR.ear".STRUCTURE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."ADTF_EAR.ear".STRUCTURE: JBAS018733: Failed to proce
ss phase STRUCTURE of deployment "ADTF_EAR.ear"
        at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:166) [wildfly-server-8.1.0.Final.jar:8
.1.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948) [jboss-msc-1.2.2.Final.jar:1.2.2.F
inal]
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881) [jboss-msc-1.2.2.Final.jar:1.2.2.Final]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]
Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: JBAS011037: Unable to process modules in application.xml for EAR ["/
usr/local/wildfly-8.1.0.Final/standalone/deployments/ADTF_EAR.ear"], module file ADTF_EJB.jar not found
        at org.jboss.as.ee.structure.EarStructureProcessor.deploy(EarStructureProcessor.java:187)
        at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:159) [wildfly-server-8.1.0.Final.jar:8
.1.0.Final]
        ... 5 more

2015-01-19 20:43:12,675 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) JBAS014613: Operation ("full-replace
-deployment") failed - address: ([]) - failure description: {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"ADTF_EAR.ear\".STRUCTURE"
 => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\"ADTF_EAR.ear\".STRUCTURE: JBAS018733: Failed to process phase STRUCT
URE of deployment \"ADTF_EAR.ear\"
    Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: JBAS011037: Unable to process modules in application.xml for EAR
 [\"/usr/local/wildfly-8.1.0.Final/standalone/deployments/ADTF_EAR.ear\"], module file ADTF_EJB.jar not found"}}
2015-01-19 20:43:12,695 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) JBAS018565: Replaced deployment "ADTF_EAR.ear" with deploymen
t "ADTF_EAR.ear"
```

I was hoping someone could help or at least point me in the right direction to fix this.  Thank you.

Comment: You have ADTF_EJB.jar specified in application.xml but it is not present in your ADTF_EAR.ear, either remove it from application.xml or add it to your ear

Comment: have a look at my response at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26272998/cannot-deploy-ear-on-wildfly-8-due-to-failures-when-processing-its-structure/30045189#30045189