# Failed to process phase STRUCTURE of deployment

Tags: jboss

I am working on migrating an application from WAS 7 to Jboss 7.1.0 final. The application was written using Java 6. Since Java 6 is only compatible with Jboss 7, I setup using the same using Jboss 7.1.0 final.
I was able to successfully build the app but while deploying I get the following error:
Can you please help me with some pointers to solve this issue?

```
10:23:11,101 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBAS015876: Starting deployment of "WSE_CustomerAccountEligibilityService.ear"
10:23:11,101 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-8) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."WSE_CustomerAccountEligibilityService.ear".STRUCTURE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."WSE_CustomerAccountEligibilityService.ear".STRUCTURE: Failed to process phase STRUCTURE of deployment "WSE_CustomerAccountEligibilityService.ear"
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:119) [jboss-as-server-7.1.0.Final.jar:7.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886) [rt.jar:1.6.0_38]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908) [rt.jar:1.6.0_38]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [rt.jar:1.6.0_38]
Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: JBAS011037: Unable to process modules in application.xml for EAR ["/C:/Kavita/Software/jboss-as-7.1.0.Final/jboss-as-7.1.0.Final/bin/content/WSE_CustomerAccountEligibilityService.ear"], module file WSW_CustomerAccountEligibilityService.war not found
    at org.jboss.as.ee.structure.EarStructureProcessor.deploy(EarStructureProcessor.java:168)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:113) [jboss-as-server-7.1.0.Final.jar:7.1.0.Final]
    ... 5 more

10:23:11,102 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (HttpManagementService-threads - 3) JBAS015870: Deploy of deployment "WSE_CustomerAccountEligibilityService.ear" was rolled back with failure message {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"WSE_CustomerAccountEligibilityService.ear\".STRUCTURE" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\"WSE_CustomerAccountEligibilityService.ear\**".STRUCTURE: Failed to process phase STRUCTURE of deployment \"WSE_CustomerAccountEligibilityService.ear\""}}**
10:23:11,102 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS015877: Stopped deployment WSE_CustomerAccountEligibilityService.ear in 0ms
10:23:11,105 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (HttpManagementService-threads - 3) JBAS014774: Service status report
JBAS014777:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.deployment.unit."WSE_CustomerAccountEligibilityService.ear".STRUCTURE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."WSE_CustomerAccountEligibilityService.ear".STRUCTURE: Failed to process phase STRUCTURE of deployment "WSE_CustomerAccountEligibilityService.ear"
```

Comment: have a look at my response at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26272998/cannot-deploy-ear-on-wildfly-8-due-to-failures-when-processing-its-structure/30045189#30045189

Answer (score 8):

```
Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: JBAS011037: Unable to process modules in application.xml for EAR ["/C:/Kavita/Software/jboss-as-7.1.0.Final/jboss-as-7.1.0.Final/bin/content/WSE_CustomerAccountEligibilityService.ear"], module file WSW_CustomerAccountEligibilityService.war not found
```

Your application.xml is declaring a war, but it's not present in the ear. Make sure your ear has all the modules declared in application.xml

Answer (score 0):

In my case, someone in the team manually copied corrupted file into the .ear folder, hence the jboss was unable to recognize/understand/unzip during deployment and throwing following exceptions.

jboss.deployment.unit."MyApp.ear".STRUCTURE: JBAS018733: Failed to process phase STRUCTURE of deployment "MyApp.ear" & org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: JBAS011060: Failed to process children for EAR

Once we removed the corrupted file present .ear folder and started jboss OR redeployment fixed the issue.

Corrupted jar in any of child war/WEB-INF/lib folders also can cause this issue.

Comment: Maybe lemmings?

Answer (score -1):

I found the same error with JBoss 7.1.0 and Java 6 EE. I solved with an upgrate to JBoss 7.1.1.